How actually Istio ServiceEntry work with ServiceEntry?
I have a k8s cluster and an app app1, calling external app extApp.
I also have a Istio ServiceEntry:
    apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: foo
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  hosts:
    - extApp.bar
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL
  ports:
    - name: "http-content-80"
      number: 80
      protocol: "HTTP"
  resolution: STATIC
  endpoints:
  - address: 172.11.14.17

But i got an exception:
io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext$SearchDomainUnknownHostException

So, how the external routing is supposed to work?
Should extApp.bar be in k8s Core Dns ?
